# Exponenciación Rapida en C

Tags: c

buenas. Tengo una consulta y es en base a un problema de exponenciación para cuando se trabaja con números grandes en criptografía. Ejemplo:

> si realizo la operación 4^5 mod 91, se puede realizar primero 4^5 y
>   después realizar mod 91, es decir, realizar operaciones parciales.
>   Pero si, en cambio, tengo 53972^753 mod 3655147, no es viable realizar
>   operaciones parciales, puesto que elevar ese esa base a ese exponente,
>   seria obtener un resultado de mas de 3000 dígitos.

He aquí donde entra en juego lo que se conoce como: **"Algoritmo de exponenciación rápida"**. Dejo a continuación el pseudo-código:

```
/*
A^B mod n
Representar B en binario= b[k-1] b[k-2] ... b[i]... b[1][0]

Hacer x= 1

Para i= k-1, 0 hacer
    Si (b[i] = 0) entonces x= x^2 mod n
    Si no si(b[i] = 1) entonces x= x^2 * A mod n

Devolver x 
*/
```

Realmente no tiene demasiada complejidad y la verdad que su utilización me parece muy eficiente, pero cuando lo voy a codificar en lenguaje C, no entiendo porque no funciona. Dejo aquí el código a ver si alguien me puede dar una mano para ver en que estoy fallando. Desde ya gracias.
Código en C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TAM 100
typedef int _vector[TAM];

long aBinario(int x);
int contarDigitos(long x);
int expRapida(int a, int b, int n);
int expRapida1(int a, int b, int n, long bin, int contador, _vector v);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int a, b, n; //base, exponente, cuerpo de trabajo

    printf("Ingrese base: "); scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Ingrese exponente: "); scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Ingrese valor para n: "); scanf("%d", &n);

    int x= expRapida(a, b, n);

    printf("Valor x= %d\n", x);
    //printf("Cantiadad de numeros binarios: %d\n", contarDigitos(aBinario(b)));
    //printf("Binario: %ld\n", aBinario(b));

    return 0;
}

long aBinario(int x){
    if(x == 0) return x;
    else return aBinario(x/2) * 10 + x%2;
}

int contarDigitos(long x){
    if(x == 0) return 0;
    else return contarDigitos(x/10) + 1;
}

int expRapida(int a, int b, int n){
    _vector v;
    long bin= aBinario(b);
    int contador;

    if(bin != 0) contador= contarDigitos(bin);
    else contador= 1;

    return expRapida1(a, b, n, bin, contador, v);
}

int expRapida1(int a, int b, int n, long bin, int contador, _vector v){
    int i;
    long x;
    for(i= 0; i < contador; i+= 1){
        v[i]= bin%10;
        bin= bin/10;    
    }

    x= 1;
    for(i= 0; i < contador; i+= 1){
        if(v[i] == 0) x= (long)pow(x, 2) % n;
        else if(v[i] == 1) x= (long)pow(x, 2) * a % n; 
    }  
    return x;
}
```

No entiendo porque no funciona con números relativamente grandes.
*Cifrado:*
**C = M^e mod n**
*Descifrado:*
**M= C^d mod n**
Por ejemplo, con estos valores funciona:
Cifrado con Clave Pública: (3,253)
M = 18 4 6 20 17 8 3 0 3

- 18^3 = 5832 mod 253 = 13
- 4^3 = 64 mod 253 = 64
- 6^3 = 216 mod 253 = 216
- 20^3 = 8000 mod 253 = 157
- 17^3 = 4913 mod 253 = 106
- 8^3 = 512 mod 253 = 6
- 3^3 = 27 mod 253 = 27
- 0^3 = 0 mod 253 = 0
- 3^3 = 27 mod 253 = 27

C = 13 64 216 157 106 6 27 0 27

Pero con estos números NO funciona:
Descifrado con Clave Privada: (147,253)
C = 13 64 216 157 106 6 27 0 27

- 13^147 mod 253 = 18
- 64^147 mod 253 = 4
- 216^147 mod 253 = 6
- 157^147 mod 253 = 20
- 106^147 mod 253 = 17
- 6^147 mod 253 = 8
- 27^147 mod 253 = 3
- 0^147 mod 253 = 0
- 27^147 mod 253 = 3

M = 18 4 6 20 17 8 3 0 3

Comment: Veo que el `M` que obtienes descifrando `C` te devuelve el valor original, ¿por qué dices que no funciona? Recuerda que necesitamos tanto el valor esperado como el obtenido para ayudarte. Adicionalmente, aunque está bien tener un poco de contexto, si el error es de exponenciación no expliques el problema en clave de cifrado/descifrado; si el error es que `13^147 mod 253` da un valor incorrecto realmente da igual para lo que se use luego ese valor. Poner tanta información innecesaria puede confundir a quien lea la pregunta.

Comment: Tenes razon, esta demas la información, pense que si explicaba para que se usaba por ahí se entendia mejor porque se utilizaba ese algoritmo. Pero te entiendo, para la proxima pregunta lo voy a tener en cuenta. Gracias.

Comment: A ver, no digo que no expliques el contexto -algunas veces ayuda-, pero que mejor si centras la información (especialmente sobre que valores pruebas, que valores esperas y que valores obtienes) en el código con problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu algoritmo de conversión a binario deja que desear:

```
long aBinario(int x){
    if(x == 0) return x;
    else return aBinario(x/2) * 10 + x%2;
}
```

`int` puede ocupar 2 o 4 bytes (lo típico son 4) y `long` ocupa 4 bytes. Esto nos impone un límite bastante serio... en cuanto la representación binaria de un número ocupe más de 10 dígitos (2^32 = 4,294,967,295 -> 10 dígitos) tu algoritmo va a fallar. Esto nos dice que tu algoritmo va a funcionar bien con números inferiores a 1024 (2^10).

Lo lógico sería guardar la representación directamente en un vector. Como trabajas con números de 32 bits la representación binaria de cualquier número no va a ocupar más de 32 posiciones (tu has puesto un límite de 100).

Conocer el número de dígitos que va a ocupar el número en su conversión a binario es tan sencillo como usar `log2`:

```
int digitos = log2(numero)+1;
```

En efecto podemos verificar que:

```
2(10 = 10(2 -> log2(2)+1 = 1+1 = 2 digitos
1024(10 = 10000000000(2 -> log2(1024)+1 = 10+1 = 11 digitos
```

Este dato te puede servir para evitar tener que darle la vuelta al vector:

```
void aBinario(int x, _vector vector, int* digitos){
  *digitos = log2(x)+1;

  for( int i = *digitos-1; i >= 0; i-- )
  {
    vector[i] = x % 2;
    x /= 2;
  }
}
```

Por otro lado, si asumimos que `v` contiene una secuencia binaria (1 y 0) el `else if` de `expRapida1` es totalmente redundante (si el valor no es 0 necesariamente tendrá que ser 1). En los algoritmos, especialmente los matemáticos, es crucial simplificar las operaciones al máximo:

```
for(i= 0; i < contador; i+= 1){
    if(v[i] == 0) x= (long)pow(x, 2) % n;
    else x= (long)pow(x, 2) * a % n; 
}
```

Además, `expRapida1` no necesita usar `b` ya que su valor se lo estás proporcionando en binario a través de `v`. El código actualizado podría quedar así:

```
int expRapida(int a, int b, int n){
    _vector v;
    int digitos;
    aBinario(b,v,&digitos);

    return expRapida1(a, n, v, digitos);
}

int expRapida1(int a, int n, _vector v, int digitos){
    long x = 1;

    for(int i= 0; i < digitos; i+= 1){
        if(v[i] == 0) x= (long)pow(x, 2) % n;
        else x= (long)pow(x, 2) * a % n; 
    }  
    return x;
}
```

Vamos a probar el código con tus datos de ejemplo. El código de prueba:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  int a, b, n; //base, exponente, cuerpo de trabajo

  scanf("%d", &b);
  scanf("%d", &n);

  while( scanf("%d", &a) > 0 )
  {
    int x= expRapida(a, b, n);

    printf("Valor x= %d\n", x);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Para poder operar en bucle primero coje el exponente y n y finalmente la base en bucle.

**Prueba 1**

Entrada:

```
3
253
18 4 6 20 17 8 3 0 3
```

Salida:

```
Valor x= 13
Valor x= 64
Valor x= 216
Valor x= 157
Valor x= 106
Valor x= 6
Valor x= 27
Valor x= 0
Valor x= 27
```

**Prueba 2**

Entrada:

```
147
253
13 64 216 157 106 6 27 0 27
```

Salida:

```
Valor x= 18
Valor x= 4
Valor x= 6
Valor x= 20
Valor x= 17
Valor x= 8
Valor x= 3
Valor x= 0
Valor x= 3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @eferion. No sabia lo de log2. Lo unico que no entendi es la notacion es utilizaste: 2(10 = 10(2 -> log2(2)+1 = 1+1 = 2 digitos
1024(10 = 10000000000(2 -> log2(1024)+1 = 10+1 = 11 digitos. O sea, 2(10 = 10(2 y 1024(10 = 10000000000(2.

Comment: **Después al main lo deje de la siguiente manera:** ` int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
 int a, b, n; //base, exponente, cuerpo de trabajo

 do{

  printf("Ingrese base: "); scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("Ingrese exponente: "); scanf("%d", &b);
  printf("Ingrese valor para n: "); scanf("%d", &n); 

 if(a >= 0){
  int x= expRapida(a, b, n);
  printf("Valor x= %d\n", x);
  break;
 }

 }while( a < 0);

 
 return 0;
} `

Comment: @Fesa 2(10 -> 2 en base 10, mientras que 10(2 es notación binaria. Con respecto al segundo comentario no veo a donde quieres ir a parar, si tienes dudas nuevas o si tienes algun problema (los comentarios no están pensados para poner varias líneas de código)

Comment: muchas gracias @eferion entendi perfecto ahora, solo cambie el main que pusiste, porque sino para salir de la consola tenia que presionar ctrl + c, despues funciona perfecto el codigo, lo simplifcaste muy bien, te agradesco la verdad por la explicación detallada. Me di cuenta porque no funcionaba. Una vez mas gracias!!!

Comment: @Fesa si la respuesta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como solución para ayudar a futuros visitantes.

Comment: Si, me di cuenta que no puedo poner varias lineas de codigo, no solo era un detalle, para anclar en el bucle si ingresa un valor negativo, que tambien lo saque de tu codigo, detalles nada mas. Lo mas importante ya esta. muchas gracias! :)

Comment: Listo! marcada como solución. Manejas re bien c, gracias!